# How to convert yyyymmdd date to proper format in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I've tried to convert a series of date where the format is `yyyymmdd` to executable pandas `datetime` format.

`20180331` to `2018-03-31`

Timestamp method is giving error.

Comment: pd.to_datetime('20180331 ')

Comment: Always post a bit of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas to_datetime to convert

```
pd.to_datetime('20180331 ')
```

Out:

```
Timestamp('2018-03-31 00:00:00')
```

and  you can make use of strip time to extract your required information of days, month ,year etc

```
%m - month of timestamp
%y - year with last 2 digts
%Y - year of timestamp
%d - date of timestamp
%H - hours of timestmap
%M - minutes of timestamp


pd.to_datetime('20180331 ').strftime('%Y:%m:%d')
```

Out:

```
'2018:03:31'
```